# Communication between domains using Amazon S3 service and Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, amazon-s3, sandbox

Does anyone have any tips on working with Amazon S3 service and Flash? I am building a HTML/SWF that will be hosted on *domain A* (My server). The main SWF will load files (SWF, XML) from *domain B* (Amazon S3 Bucket) and the will be communicating with each other. I read somewhere that you can add a crossdomain.xml in your bucket so there should not be any sandbox problems right?

Any thoughts, tips or ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't had any issues regarding the need for a crossdomain policy on the s3 bucket however, I have had to perform Security.allowDomain() and Security.allowInsecureDomain(), since all s3 assets that were loaded are coming from a secure bucket, and that the swf was hosted on an insecure domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all works. Just drop a `crossdomain.xml` file in the root of each bucket that you need to access. Make sure that you set its ACL settings to `public` for all users.

Here's [an article](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/2011) in the AWS docs explaining more.